# Can anyone identify this frame possible brand Sergio?

Tags: identify-this-bike, vintage

I bought a road bike frame with no manufacturers name and a barely visible sticker which I think says Nova, it has Sergio stamped on the seat stays where it meets the seat tube. The rear dropouts are campagnolo brev and it has cable guides welded to the top of the bottom bracket. There are no cable guides or mounts for shifters. Anyone any ideas?! Also got a box of parts with it, there's half a Shimano golden arrow groupset with it, and some old suntour derailleurs.  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zei99.jpg)[image][image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: We need a few good pictures. Here is how to ask a good bike ID question https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1337/how-do-i-ask-a-good-id-my-bike-question/1338#1338

Comment: @DavidD sidenote, you linked to an answer on the question: https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1337/how-do-i-ask-a-good-id-my-bike-question

Comment: @DavidD gratifying that you linked to my somewhat sarcastic answer :-)

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus I didn't mean to do it that way - but it works for me!

Comment: Added some pics

Comment: Updated with pics

Answer (score 1):

If the sticker looks something like this:

[image]

then it's probably Nova tubing and it *might* be a reasonably valuable bike.